# Exponential backoff implementation with rxjs

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

Angular 7 [docs](https://angular.io/guide/practical-observable-usage#exponential-backoff) provide this example of practical usage of `rxjs` `Observable`s in implementing an exponential backoff for an AJAX request:

```
import { pipe, range, timer, zip } from 'rxjs';
import { ajax } from 'rxjs/ajax';
import { retryWhen, map, mergeMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

function backoff(maxTries, ms) {
 return pipe(
   retryWhen(attempts => range(1, maxTries)
     .pipe(
       zip(attempts, (i) => i),
       map(i => i * i),
       mergeMap(i =>  timer(i * ms))
     )
   )
 );
}

ajax('/api/endpoint')
  .pipe(backoff(3, 250))
  .subscribe(data => handleData(data));

function handleData(data) {
  // ...
}
```

While I understand the concept of both Observables and backoff, I can’t quite figure out, how exactly `retryWhen` will calculate time intervals for resubscribing to the source `ajax`.

Specifically, how do [`zip`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/zip), [`map`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/map), and [`mapMerge`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/mergeMap) work in this setup?

And what’s going to be contained in the `attempts` object when it’s emitted into `retryWhen`?

I went through their reference pages, but still can’t wrap my head around this.

Comment: Rx is just somewhat confusing to learn. `retryWhen` retries on a criteria - `attempts` is  the error stream. `zip` grabs the next index from the range. `map` multiplies` it by itself (that's the exponential part since x * x is just x ** 2), mapMerge waits for the timer to finish before the next attempt continues. Piping it to the ajax will tell it to retry when the ajax errors and then back off exponentially (when the error stream emits an error - the zip continues, the map runs and the mergeMap waits for the timer before continuing).

Comment: And of course, you're welcome to just use `fetch` and implement it without Rx which would be ~5 LoC of regular JavaScript and a for loop with a try/catch :D

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum one thing I don't get is how `zip` is working here ... why doesn't it create a new Observable from `zip` each time it resubscribes?

Comment: @ExplosionPills The `retryWhen` operator only subscribes once to the observable that's composed within it. It feeds any errors received from the source to the observable composed within it - the `attempts` parameter to the arrow function is an observable of errors. Essentially, the `range` observable 'seeds' the `zip` with the number of retries that should be attempted.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum @cartant So, `zip` operator grabs the `range` observable (1, 2, 3) and merges it with the input `attempts`? But why do this? I removed `zip` from the `pipe` and the function seems to have run the same way. So what was the point of zipping? Can’t we just ignore `attempts`?

Comment: @CBlew the attempts observable "fires an item" whenever the http request fails.

Comment: @cartant I have the same question as CBlew... if it only subscribes once to the composed observable how come using just `range` by itself will resubscribe forever vs. the `zip` approach?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I have spent quite some time researching this (for learning purposes) and will try to explain the workings of this code as thoroughly as possible.

First, here’s the original code, annotated:

```
import { pipe, range, timer, zip } from 'rxjs';
import { ajax } from 'rxjs/ajax';
import { retryWhen, map, mergeMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

function backoff(maxTries, ms) {                  // (1)
 return pipe(                                     // (2)
   retryWhen(attempts => range(1, maxTries)       // (3)
     .pipe(
       zip(attempts, (i) => i),                   // (4)
       map(i => i * i),                           // (5)
       mergeMap(i =>  timer(i * ms))              // (6)
     )
   )
 );                                               // (7)
}

ajax('/api/endpoint')
  .pipe(backoff(3, 250))
  .subscribe(data => handleData(data));

function handleData(data) {
  // ...
}
```

1. Easy enough, we’re creating custom `backoff` operator out of `retryWhen` operator. We’ll be able to apply this later within `pipe` function.
2. In this context, `pipe` method returns a custom operator.
3. Our custom operator is going to be a modified `retryWhen` operator. It takes a function argument. This function is going to be called *once* — specifically, when this `retryWhen` is first encountered/invoked. By the way, `retryWhen` gets into play *only* when the source observable produces an error. It then prevents error from propagating further and resubscribes to the source. If the source produces a non-error result (whether on first subscription or on a retry), `retryWhen` is passed over and is not involved.

   A few words on `attempts`. It’s an observable. It is not the source observable. It is created specifically for `retryWhen`. It has one use and one use only: whenever subscription (or re-subscription) to the source observable results in an error, `attempts` fires a `next`. We are given `attempts` and are free to use it in order to react in some way to each failed subscription attempt to the source observable.

   So that’s what we are going to do.

   First we create `range(1, maxTries)`, an observable that has an integer for every retry we are willing to perform. `range` is ready to fire all it’s numbers right then and there, but we have to hold its horses: we only need a new number when another retry happens. So, that’s why we...
4. ... zip it with the `attempts`. Meaning, marry each emitted value of `attempts` with a single value of `range`.

   Remember, function we’re currently in is going to be called only once, and at that time, `attempts` will have only fired `next` once — for the initial failed subscription. So, at this point, our two zipped observables have produced just one value.

   Btw, what are the values of the two observables zipped into one? This function decides that: `(i) => i`. For clarity it can be written `(itemFromRange, itemFromAttempts) => itemFromRange`. Second argument is not used, so it’s dropped, and first is renamed into `i`.

   What happens here, is we simply disregard the *values* fired by `attempts`, we are only interested in the *fact* that they are fired. And whenever that happens we pull the next value from `range` observable...
5. ...and square it. This is for the *exponential* part of the exponential backoff.

   So, now whenever (re-)subscription to source fails, we have an ever increasing integer on our hands (1, 4, 9, 16...). How do we transform that integer into a time delay until next re-subscription?

   Remember, this function we are currently inside of, it must return an observable, using `attempts` as input. This resulting observable is only built once. `retryWhen` then subscribes to that resulting observable and: retries subscribing to source observable whenever resulting observable fires `next`; calls `complete` or `error` on source observable whenever resulting observable fires those corresponding events.
6. Long story short, we need to make `retryWhen` wait a bit. [`delay`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-delay) operator could maybe be used, but setting up exponential growth of the delay would likely be pain. Instead, `mergeMap` operator comes into play.

   `mergeMap` is a shortcut for two operators combined: `map` and `mergeAll`. `map` simply converts every increasing integer (1, 4, 9, 16...) into a `timer` observable which fires `next` after passed number of milliseconds. `mergeAll` forces `retryWhen` to actually subscribe to `timer`. If that last bit didn’t happen, our resulting observable would just fire `next` immediately with `timer` observable instance as value.
7. At this point, we’ve built our custom observable which will be used by `retryWhen` to decide when exactly to attempt to re-subscribe to source observable.

As it stands I see two problems with this implementation:

- As soon as our resulting observable fires its last `next` (causing the last attempt to resubscribe), it also immediately fires `complete`. Unless the source observable returns result *very* quickly (assuming that the very last retry will be the one that succeeds), that result is going to be ignored.

  This is because as soon as `retryWhen` hears `complete` from our observable, it calls `complete` on source, which may still be in the process of making AJAX request.
- If all retries were unsuccessful, source actually calls `complete` instead of more logical `error`.

To solve both these issues, I think that our resulting observable should fire `error` at the very end, after giving the last retry some reasonable time to attempt to do its job.

Here’s my implementation of said fix, which also takes into account deprecation of `zip` operator in latest `rxjs v6`:

```
import { delay, dematerialize, map, materialize, retryWhen, switchMap } from "rxjs/operators";
import { concat, pipe, range, throwError, timer, zip } from "rxjs";

function backoffImproved(maxTries, ms) {
    return pipe(
        retryWhen(attempts => {
            const observableForRetries =
                zip(range(1, maxTries), attempts)
                    .pipe(
                        map(([elemFromRange, elemFromAttempts]) => elemFromRange),
                        map(i => i * i),
                        switchMap(i => timer(i * ms))
                    );
            const observableForFailure =
                throwError(new Error('Could not complete AJAX request'))
                    .pipe(
                        materialize(),
                        delay(1000),
                        dematerialize()
                    );
            return concat(observableForRetries, observableForFailure);
        })
    );
}
```

I tested this code and it seems to work properly in all cases. I can’t be bothered to explain it in detail right now; I doubt anyone will even read the wall of text above.

Anyway, big thanks to @BenjaminGruenbaum and @cartant for setting me onto right path for wrapping my head around all this.

Comment: That looks to be overly complicated. You might want to have a look at Alex's implementation: https://github.com/alex-okrushko/backoff-rxjs

Comment: I actually did read the wall of text - a very interesting case for [de]materialize. I will see if I can aggregate errors of all the retries and emit it in on the retryWhen's output

Answer (score 1):

Here is a different version that can be easily extended/modified:

```
import { Observable, pipe, throwError, timer } from 'rxjs';
import { mergeMap, retryWhen } from 'rxjs/operators';

export function backoff(maxRetries = 5): (_: Observable<any>) => Observable<any> {
  return pipe(
    retryWhen(errors => errors.pipe(
      mergeMap((error, i) => {
        const retryAttempt = i + 1;
        if (retryAttempt > maxRetries) {
          return throwError(error);
        } else {
          const waitms = retryAttempt * retryAttempt * 1000;
          console.log(`Attempt ${retryAttempt}: retrying in ${waitms}ms`);
          return timer(waitms);
        }
      }),
    ))
  );
};
```

Ref [retryWhen](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/error_handling/retrywhen)