# Repeating api request every x seconds

Tags: angular, rxjs

In angular I'm building chat application. I want to fetch new messages every x seconds like so:
1. 5 seconds
2. 10 seconds
3. 20 seconds - has new messages
4. 5 seconds
5. 10 seconds 
...and so on.

I tired with `repeatWhen` but it seems no to repeat request, only emits last value of completed observable.

Here is what I've got:

```
this.delay = 5000;
this.ngxsStore.fetchMessages()
   .pipe(repeatWhen(completed => completed.pipe(delay(this.delay))})
   .subscribe(resp => this.messages = resp);
```

```
  fetchMessages(store) {
    return this.api.fetchMesages()
      .pipe(
        tap(resp => {
          if (resp) {
            store.patchState({
              messages: [
                ...store.getState().messages,
                ...resp
              ]
            });
          }
        })
      );
  }
```

Comment: `repeatWhen` resubscribes to its source Observable so it depends on what `this.api.fetchMessages()` does.

Comment: In fact I'm not sending request but triggering action in `ngxs` store. Updated the code

Answer (score 0):

try add defer()

```
defer(()=>this.ngxsStore.fetchMessages())
   .pipe(repeatWhen(completed => completed.pipe(delay(this.delay))})
   .subscribe(resp => this.messages = resp);
```

Answer (score 0):

The technique is called "retry backoff".
You can find the implementation here:
[Exponential backoff implementation with rxjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53015170/exponential-backoff-implementation-with-rxjs)