# How to do polling in svelte?

Tags: polling, svelte

I have a specific app which should do the following:

1. You have a list of jobs to inspect
2. When you click a job you get a detail view
3. The detail view will poll the API to see live progress updates

I did a basic implementation in the following REPL: https://svelte.dev/repl/fcdce26dc0d843dbb4b394dcd2c838af?version=3.20.1

There are a couple of issues with this approach:

1. The `Job.svelte` view should basically reset when you provide a new id, and clear out any previous poller, but now it's super awkward with a reactive statement at the bottom
2. Because the poller does an asynchronous fetch it can happen that the timeout handler `poller` is cleared even though the handler is executing already. This causes multiple poller loops to occur (you can reproduce this by clicking through the job list at random intervals between 0 and 2 seconds)
3. The current approach is not developer friendly and is easily broken. The 'bug' above can be fixed by keeping track of a reference/lock kind of thing but then it's even harder to wrap your head around.

For this use case, what is a better way of implementing it (in Svelte)?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

> The Job.svelte view should basically reset when you provide a new id, and clear out any previous poller, but now it's super awkward with a reactive statement at the bottom

Like a previous reply already pointed out, this is the Svelte way. It's awkward at first, until you realize it's very simple, handy and elegant.

There are two things I would improve in your code:

- do away with the messy cache per ID + single progress value assignment ; this is what causes your late fetches to display visually (a late fetch reply in itself is not a bug, displaying it to your user *is*, however) ; I simply renamed your cache object to `progress` and chose to display `progress[id]`, this way a late fetch reply will update in the background, but not interfere visually with your currently displayed job
- use `setInterval` instead of multiple `setTimeout` for periodic polling

```js
<script>
    export let id

    let progress = {}
    let poller

    const setupPoller = (id) => {
        if (poller) {
            clearInterval(poller)
        }
        poller = setInterval(doPoll(id), 2000)
    }

    const doPoll = (id) => async () => {
        console.log(`polling ${id}`)
        progress[id] = await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => {
            resolve((progress[id] || 0) + 1)
        }, 500))
    }

    $: setupPoller(id)
</script>

<div>
    <p>
        ID: {id}
    </p>
    <p>
        Progress: {progress[id] || 0}
    <p>
</div>
```

See [this REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/1863732b35c146308bbcb1331e310221?version=3.20.1)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply! It really helps to understand the Svelte way better. Do you have some resources (articles, blogs) for me to read more about this? A note about your suggested improvements: in the real-life use case I want to be able to respond to completion/failure from the back-end and implement things like exponential back-off, that's why I choose `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval`.

Comment: @Wilco You are very welcome. Can't think of any specific article or blog, but I do follow the `@sveltejs` and `@SvelteSociety` accounts on Twitter. Svelte Society casted a conference last Sunday on a variety of topics (haven't had time to watch it yet but planning to): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0rnG-OlzGSs. As for the `setInterval` suggestion, it was just that, a suggestion. If your needs require a different approach, it's a perfectly valid reason. You could also have used sockets instead of polling and pushed progress updates. Many ways to skin a cat (however horrible that sounds) ;)

Answer (score 1):

I think 1. is just the way to go on Svelte. There is no `ngOnChanges` like in angular.

2./3. is a problem independent of Svelte I think. Asynchronous stuff with time races is always hard. Libraries like `rxjs` make it easier to handle this, but have a steep learning curve. An example:

```html
<script>
  import { interval, Subject } from 'rxjs';
  import { switchMap, take, map, startWith, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

  const cache = {};
  const id$ = new Subject();
  const progress$ = id$.pipe(
    // every time id$ gets a new id, start new interval
    switchMap(id => {
      return interval(1000).pipe(
        // every time the interval emits, do an api call
        switchMap(() => {
          // fake api call
          return interval(200).pipe(
            take(1),
            map(() => id + '::' + Math.random()),
            // store value in cache
            tap(value => cache[id] = value)
          );
        }),
        // start with cached value
        startWith(cache[id]),
      );
    })
  );

  let id = 1;
  function switchPoll() {
    id = id === 2 ? 1 : 2;
    id$.next(id);
  }
</script>

<p>{$progress$}</p>
<button on:click={switchPoll}>Switch</button>
```

Comment: This is cool! I've played around with rxjs before but I didn't think about it. Thanks for your reply! If the API call is taking a long time or I would like to do something like exponential back-off, a fixed interval of 1 second might not be a good idea. That's why I used `setTimeout` in the example, can you do something similar in rxjs? Thanks again!

Comment: If you fear your API might take too long, you can use `exhaustMap` instead of `switchMap`. This means if the API takes more than 1 second, the next incoming intervals are ignored as long as the inner observable (aka api call) is not completed. Exponential backoff is a little harder to implement, see here for more https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53015170/exponential-backoff-implementation-with-rxjs .

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest using the [await blocks](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/await-blocks) from svelte. With it, you have all the logic you need for asynchronous functionality out of the box, like generating a loading screen or catching errors. I modified your [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/7ddfed07ef1c421ca2a31e90d565f9a1?version=3.20.1) with a custom timeout function (sleep) to simulate data fetching from a remote server:

```
<script>    
    let selectedJob;
    let progress = 0
        function sleep(ms) {
      return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
    }

    const pollProgress = async (id) => {    
        if(progress < 10) {;
      await sleep(300)
            progress += 1
            return pollProgress(id)
        }
        return "Done"
    }   

    function handleClick(id) {
        selectedJob = id
        promise = pollProgress(id);
    }
    let promise
</script>

<style>
    .list {
        background-color: yellow;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .details {
        background-color: cyan;
    }
</style>

<div class="list">
  {#each new Array(10).fill().map((_, i) => i) as i}
       <div on:click={() => (handleClick(i))}>
             Job {i}
         </div>
    {/each}
</div>

{#if selectedJob !== undefined}
    <div class="details">
        <h2>Job details</h2>
        <div>
        <p>
        ID: {selectedJob}
    </p>
{#await promise}
    <p>Progress: {progress}</p>
{:then res}
    <p>
        Progress: {res}
    </p>
{:catch error}
    <p style="color: red">{error.message}</p>
{/await}
</div>
    </div>
{/if}
```

It will display an updating progress to simulate polling while it is fetching the data and the string *Done*, which it receives as a result from the async function, when it is finished.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply! I would like to repeatedly poll for progress, not just once, so this solution does not fit my use case.

Comment: I updated the repl and my code with a recursive function with simulates the wished polling functionality. Please take a look.

Comment: Thanks for the updated code! It's an interesting approach to recursively spawn a new Promise, I haven't thought about that. However, the progress is now shared between jobs and if I switch jobs and print in the console I can see the promise chains are not interrupted, this means that your example suffers from the same issues that I described in the initial post.